# Margin property overrides other properties when concatenate styles in react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I currently have these two styles:

```
  indentLeft: {
    marginLeft:'4%',
  },
  forwardButtonLocation: {
    flex: 1, 
    flexDirection: 'column', 
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
```

I followed this tutorial https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html and concatenated them like this:

```
<View style={styles.forwardButtonLocation, styles.indentLeft}>
```

However, it seems like the latter style overrides the previous one even `indentLeft` and `forwardButtonLocation` don't share same properties. The button is either padded on top with `20` or indented by `4%` depending on which one comes to the second in the concatenation, but according to the tutorial, it should have both properties. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to provide multiple styles to the same element you need to the pass the styles within `[]`

```
<View style={[styles.forwardButtonLocation, styles.indentLeft]}>
```

Passing them directly in `{}` will only allow the last one to take effect

Comment: Totally missed [] . Thank you so much!